# Calculation of an equation using three vectors in r

Tags: r, if-statement, functional-programming

I am trying to calculate an equation which requires three pieces of information.

Suppose I have 5 subjects and each answered 3 questions consisting of 4 options.

The dataset of the responses from the 5 subjects is a.

```
a<-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:4),15,replace=T),nrow=5))
colnames(a)<-c("a1","a2","a3")
> a
  a1 a2 a3
1  2  1  2
2  1  4  4
3  1  1  1
4  3  4  1
5  2  2  3
```

Each option for each question has its own value. For example, the second option of the first question has the value of .7319431. The dataset is b.

```
b<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(12,0,1),nrow=3))
colnames(b)<-c("b1","b2","b3","b4")
> b
          b1        b2        b3        b4
1 0.83721477 0.7319431 0.5227578 0.9924321
2 0.02150756 0.7681706 0.8250167 0.1252194
3 0.27294672 0.8310693 0.9333875 0.8516141
```

Also, each subject has its own value. The dataset is c.

```
c<-runif(5,0,1)
> c
[1] 0.9119466 0.9053619 0.5087231 0.2063420 0.1401520
```

At the first step, for each subject and each question, I needed to multiply each value for each option with each value for each subject and then sum them up to get a number for each question and each subject. I completed this step with a function below.

```
fun<-function(b,c){
  bc1<-t(sapply(c, FUN=function(x) b[,1]*x))
  bc2<-t(sapply(c, FUN=function(x) b[,2]*x))
  bc3<-t(sapply(c, FUN=function(x) b[,3]*x))
  bc4<-t(sapply(c, FUN=function(x) b[,4]*x))
  sum<-bc1+bc2+bc3+bc4
}
```

But as the next step, I should consider the first dataset, a, such that the multiplication happens only to the case of response in the dataset, a. In other words, in the example above, for the first subject and the first question, I only need to multiply the value of the second option for the first question (.7319431) with the value for the first subject(.9119466). For the second question for the same subject, I need to calculate .02150756 (value of the first option of the second question) * .9119466 (value of the first subject).

I am currently stuck in this step. I tried to apply if-else function here, but nothing was successful. If anyone can help me to this step, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to melt all the data frames in "long format" and then join them together:

```
#subject answers data
a<-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:4),15,replace=T),nrow=5))
colnames(a)<-paste0("question",1:3)
a$subject<-paste0("subject",1:5)
#melting the data
a=melt(a,measure.vars = c('question1',"question2","question3"),value.name = "chosen_answer",variable.name = "question")

#questions score data
b<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(12,0,1),nrow=3))
colnames(b)<-1:4
b$question<-paste0("question",1:3)
    b=melt(b,measure.vars=c("1","2","3","4"),value.name="question_score",variable.name="chosen_answer")

#joining questions score with subject answers
a=merge(a,b)

#subject score data
c<-data.frame(subject_score=runif(5,0,1),subject=paste0("subject",1:5))

a=merge(a,c)
a

    subject  question chosen_answer question_score subject_score
1  subject1 question1             4      0.8847954     0.5039638
2  subject1 question2             4      0.6780376     0.5039638
3  subject1 question3             4      0.3810658     0.5039638
4  subject2 question1             2      0.8054086     0.2152930
5  subject2 question2             4      0.6780376     0.2152930
6  subject2 question3             1      0.8296518     0.2152930
7  subject3 question1             4      0.8847954     0.5769765
8  subject3 question3             2      0.7000839     0.5769765
9  subject3 question2             3      0.5875164     0.5769765
10 subject4 question3             2      0.7000839     0.5738833
11 subject4 question1             2      0.8054086     0.5738833
12 subject4 question2             1      0.6064660     0.5738833
13 subject5 question2             3      0.5875164     0.1566587
14 subject5 question1             4      0.8847954     0.1566587
15 subject5 question3             4      0.3810658     0.1566587
```

After that, you can do whatever you want with that data.

It is not exactly clear what you want to do anyway. Your function seems to multiply question scores by subject scores, regardless of what option that subject has chosen. It would help if you provide an example of expected output

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. The function I wrote in the question is what I already did (the multiplication regardless of the option). And with your approach, I believe I can get what I wanted to get, which is the multiplication question scores by subject score in your terminology. A problem is that in fact, I have more than 100,000 samples with 150 questions. If I switch the format like you, then the data will be very huge. So I'm wondering if you know another approach without changing the shape. Thanks!!